# should I use 's in this sentence

Tags: grammar

Should I use `'s` after incoming flows in this sentence?

> it is responsible for incoming flows management

or

> it is responsible for incoming flows' management

I'm talking about data flows that enter a network. I'm talking about how these flows are managed by the network.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say for certain without context - but I think you should use *neither*.

- *Incoming flow's management* would be the management belonging to Incoming Flow. That doesn't make much sense.
- *Incoming flows management* would be the management of multiple flows - how many flows do you have?

If you are talking about the flow of *income* (eg money received by a business), this is usually spoken of in the *singular*, even though it may come from many sources (eg "cashflow").

Therefore I think the term you should be using is simply *Incoming flow management*.

Comment: I'm talking about the data flows that enter a network. I'm talking about how these flows are managed by the network.